# Group by a CAST field in the select section?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, casting

I have a field in my main SELECT section that I want to group by in my report.

```
CAST((SELECT attribute_value.attrib_value_name 
FROM attribute_value,
attribute_type 
WHERE attribute_type.attrib_type_code = 'SC17' 
AND attribute_type.attrib_type_code = attribute_value.attrib_type_code 
AND attribute_value.attrib_value_code = feat_attrib_type.attrib_value_code  ) as VARCHAR (30)) as ZONE_SPEC,
```

I've tried putting the same code in the group section of the SQL but it keeps coming back with an error message

"ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended"

The code I've got so far is:

```
select

CAST((SELECT attribute_value.attrib_value_name 
FROM attribute_value,
attribute_type 
WHERE attribute_type.attrib_type_code = 'SC17' 
AND attribute_type.attrib_type_code = attribute_value.attrib_type_code 
AND attribute_value.attrib_value_code = feat_attrib_type.attrib_value_code  ) as VARCHAR (30)) as ZONE_SPEC,
feature_type.feature_type_name,

sum (feat_measurement.feature_quantity)


from
feature
inner join feature_type on feature.feature_type_code = feature_type.feature_type_code
inner join area on feature.area_code = area.area_code
inner join feat_measurement on feature.plot_number = feat_measurement.plot_number 
and feature.site_code = feat_measurement.site_code
inner join measurement_type on feat_measurement.measurement_code = measurement_type.measurement_code
inner join feat_attrib_type on feature.site_code = feat_attrib_type.site_code AND
feature.plot_number = feat_attrib_type.plot_number

where
measurement_type.measurement_code in ('AREA') and
feature.feature_deadflag = 'N'

group by 
CAST((SELECT attribute_value.attrib_value_name 
FROM attribute_value,
attribute_type 
WHERE attribute_type.attrib_type_code = 'SC17' 
AND attribute_type.attrib_type_code = attribute_value.attrib_type_code 
AND attribute_value.attrib_value_code = feat_attrib_type.attrib_value_code  ) as VARCHAR (30)) as ZONE_SPEC,

feature_type.feature_type_name

order by
feature_type.feature_type_name
```

Is it possible to add this CAST field into the group by field? And if so, how?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY's column alias attempt `as ZONE_SPEC`.

Comment: When I tried GROUP BY ZONE_SPEC, feature_type.featrue_type_name I get error message  ORA-00904: "ZONE_SPEC": invalid identidier

Comment: Use a `JOIN`.  I don't think you can aggregate by a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to accomplish is Casting an Expression in a Group By Clause, I don't think that is allowed. However you might be able to achieve the desired result by using a partition. I have edited the code a little.....

```
select
feature_type.feature_type_name,
sum (feat_measurement.feature_quantity) OVER (Partition by CAST((SELECT attribute_value.attrib_value_name 
FROM attribute_value,
attribute_type 
WHERE attribute_type.attrib_type_code = 'SC17' 
AND attribute_type.attrib_type_code = attribute_value.attrib_type_code 
AND attribute_value.attrib_value_code = feat_attrib_type.attrib_value_code  ) as VARCHAR (30)))as ZONE_SPEC

from
feature
inner join feature_type on feature.feature_type_code = feature_type.feature_type_code
inner join area on feature.area_code = area.area_code
inner join feat_measurement on feature.plot_number = feat_measurement.plot_number 
and feature.site_code = feat_measurement.site_code
inner join measurement_type on feat_measurement.measurement_code = measurement_type.measurement_code
inner join feat_attrib_type on feature.site_code = feat_attrib_type.site_code AND
feature.plot_number = feat_attrib_type.plot_number

where
measurement_type.measurement_code in ('AREA') and
feature.feature_deadflag = 'N'

group by 
feat_measurement.feature_quantity,
feat_attrib_type.attrib_value_code,
feature_type.feature_type_name

order by
feature_type.feature_type_name
```

Hope this helps.